# what does this code mean ?

Tags: c, arm, cortex-m

I'm reading a project , and I found this code, which I don't unterstand.

```
#define OUT_PINS            {X2_PIN, PIOC, ID_PIOC, PIO_OUTPUT_0, PIO_DEFAULT}, \
                    {Y2_PIN, PIOC, ID_PIOC, PIO_OUTPUT_0, PIO_DEFAULT}, \
                    {Z2_PIN, PIOC, ID_PIOC, PIO_OUTPUT_0, PIO_DEFAULT}
```

the program is running on SAM3S a cortex M3 from Atmel .

X2_Pin , Y2_Pin and Z2_Pin  are defined .

can anyone explain o me what `OUT_PINS` now is ?

Comment: `OUT_PINS` is a #define preprocessor used in a 2D array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OUT_PINS` is a macro defined with some 2D array values. check the following example for better understanding.

eg: `int *OP[] = {OUT_PINS }` is similar to

```
int *OP[] = {{X2_PIN, PIOC, ID_PIOC, PIO_OUTPUT_0, PIO_DEFAULT}, \
                    {Y2_PIN, PIOC, ID_PIOC, PIO_OUTPUT_0, PIO_DEFAULT}, \
                    {Z2_PIN, PIOC, ID_PIOC, PIO_OUTPUT_0, PIO_DEFAULT}}
```

Comment: thanks for replying, but does it do I mean why do I need that ?

Comment: If you use macro then any value changed in only macro definition will effect the entire code where ever macro is used. other wise you need to change every place in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in this case you dont really need this macro. But it brings your code a better overview. If u work with macros/defines and you need changes in your code you only have to change your macros/defines.